# Interaction between jQuery .ready() and <script defer>

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred-loading

I am trying to figure out a problem with some code I have inherited.

I have an HTML page with

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js" defer="defer"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

file1.js has

```js
FOO = {
  init : function () {
    var bar = BAR;
  }
}

$(document).ready(FOO.init);
```

file2.js has

```js
var BAR = {
}
```

Because of the defer attribute on the  elements, is it safe to assume that when the `.ready()` calls `FOO.init()` that `BAR` may still be undefined at that point b/c the code in `file2.js` hasn't executed yet because of the deferred execution?

This would match a bug I am trying to track down (only occurs sporadically in IE), but I really want to understand *why* this is happening before I work on a solution.  I have no idea why the original developer used `defer`, other than a cryptic commend about "he had to" do it this way.

Comment: Don't have an answer, but I feel for you, man.

Comment: Do you understand the `defer`attribute? 'Cause it seems to me it's a very common thing to do...

Comment: I guess the original developer wanted another script to be loaded before file1.js and file2.js (or he did not know about $(document).ready()...)

Comment: @DanielRibeiro, I understand what is documented about it at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script, but I have never had to use it.

Comment: Well, according to the documentation, `...since this feature (defer) hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred.` And it's meant to wait for the loading of the document, and not some specific script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defer should cause the script to be added to a queue that is processed after the page is completely loaded. According to the spec deferred scripts should be added to the queue in the order they came onto the page.

However different browsers have done slightly different things with the order. IE seems to run defer scripts in the order they finished loading rather than the order they occurred on the page. So you seeing the error sporadically because sometimes it's loading them in the right order and sometimes not.

See [this post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/defer/) on hacks.mozilla.com for a more exhaustive explanation and examples of how different browsers handle the ordering of the defer queue.

Answer (score 1):

[Deffering](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/defer/) in javascript gives preference to the browser of when to interpret the script, in some optimal conditions like with chrome the script is downloaded while the page is being loaded then parsed and interpreted. If you use defer like the above you can never be certain which script is loaded first or when the interpretation is complete.

`BAR` could be undefined on one page load and be defined on the reload (cached) or the second script was loaded first.

To test this try make a change to one of the scripts to force a new download and interpretation and see what race conditions exist.